# Post Array from JavaScript to PHP Post

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, http-post

I have a php file that normally takes input array from an html multiple select box, and I need a way to post that data from JScript code in another file.

As I understand it, JQuery post would work nicely for this, however that will not work in IE. Is there any easy way to pass an array of values through JavaScript so that its contents can be accessed through the $_POST array, just as if they were from an HTML multiple select box AND works in IE?

Comment: What makes you think jQuery wouldn't work in IE?

Answer (score 2):

> however that will not work in IE

I don't know where this idea comes from. I can assure you that the jQuery's [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method works more than perfectly fine in IE. For example:

```
var array = $('#multiSelectId').val();
$.post('/foo.php', { data: array }, function(result) {
    // TODO: process the results
});
```

Comment: That idea came from here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ ---- First Comment: "jQuery Post doesn't work in Internet Explorer is there any settings for this method", but if you're right I'll just go ahead and do it that way, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript side

```
 var arrayToPost= new Array(1, 2, 3);
    arrayToPost = JSON.stringify(arrayToPost );
```

will poste this string : [1,2,3]

PHP side

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST['arrayToPost']));
```

result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('/path/to/handler.php', $('form').serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [xAjax](http://www.xajax-project.org/), a nice PHP-libraty to simplify [AJAX using PHP](http://www.xajax-project.org/).